# Format mask a currency amount in Oracle ApEx

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a cost field in my Oracle ApEx form where the user may enter an $ amount of say 10000.00 or more or even less.

My question is, how to format mask and validate this value within my ApEx form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you just need the settings of the item?
For example, when you create or edit an item of type number field, you can set the following (Edit Page Item):

[image]

Comment: Thanks again Tom but what about when it comes to validating a dollar amount field to ensure that a dollar amount is entered?

Comment: When the field is a number item, do you need more validation than that? Of course, the stored value would be a simple number (your column wouldn't hold a $-sign of course). But any entered number would be fine, no? If you would enter characters, then on submit the built-in validation will give an error: "Currency does not match number format FML999G999G999G999G990D00 (Example: $1,251.49)." Should you require more on-the-fly control, then the only option would be javascript, to provide validation (ie: is number?)